# How to define image src using double quotes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, src

I'm trying to create an array of 29 images using a loop, but can't properly define image.src using double quotes.I try to use escape character but it doesn't work any way.

Do you have any ideas?

Here is my code

```
var myImages = []; 
for (var j=0;j<29;j++){
myImages[j]=new Image();
myImages[j].src="\"im\"+j+\".png\"";
}
```

Comment: what is the image src name you wish to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

You only need escaped double quotes (`\"`) if you want double quotes as part of string itself, or equivalently in this case, if the file name actually contains them, but I suspect this is not the case.

If your files are named `im<k>.png`, where `<k>` is an integer number, then the correct solution would be to do this in line four:

```
myImages[j].src = "im" + j + ".png";
```

Answer (score 1):

`myImages[j].src = "im"+j+".png";`

Answer (score 0):

you can use single quotes directly if you want to add some double quotes in your image src attribute .

```
image.src = '"image"' + '.jpg';
```